# online Javascript code evaluation tools

Tags: javascript, debugging

Do you have a favorite site or homegrown page in your toolbox to help you during development of your Javascript?

Something to help you:

- validate
- run
- debug, inspect
- unit test

Looking for somewhere to paste my JS into, click a Run button, and have it evaluate the statements.  This might be for simple snippets for manipulation of numbers, strings, custom objects, etc.

**ANSWER** (since no answers before the question was closed actually address the requirements:

- [turb0js](http://www.turb0js.com/) - lets you step through the code without having to open the browser's console and hunt for the right JavaScript file. Also allows adding an HTML description to the code snippet, and comments from other users. DOM and Console methods don't work.
- jsbin with [`// noprotect`](http://jsbin.com/blog/protection#comment-1590869196) at the beginning of the code, to enable debugging in the browser console

Non-answers: Codepen (can't debug due to its autorun on edit creating a new script); JSFiddle (no direct support for the browser console)

Comment: http://codepen.io overall is the best one I found so far, including those mentioned in here. I never found any that worked that you can set break points or use debugging features in though, as you can in the Chrome tools.

Comment: [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=edit) has a nice JavaScript visualizer. so far my solution has been setting up a dedicated blank page and js file and edit/reload/debug in Chrome (which has a helpful [Live Editing](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#liveedit) feature)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give a look to [JsBin](http://jsbin.com) it's a great online tool for collaborative JavaScript debugging...

You can easily incorporate the most popular JavaScript libraries, and you can even use it for Ajax Request Debugging...

Check the [introductory videos](http://jsbin.com/videos)...

Comment: +1, totally forgot about JS Bin, but it's good stuff.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - looks like an amazingly useful tool.

Comment: [JSBin doesn't let you easily debug JavaScript code.](http://jsbin.com/blog/protection#comment-1590869196) You have to open the browser console, hunt for the correct JavaScript file in the Scripts tab, then debug quickly enough that the loop protection doesn't kill execution because it thinks your script is running too slowly. (or add `//no protect` to the top of the code).

Answer (score 10):

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) is what you need

Comment: jsfiddle.net doesn't allow direct running of javascript statements right? It's the complete HTML/JS/CSS integration results that are displayed. No Javascript console as such

Answer (score 5):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) helps a lot for validating JS.

In terms of running/debugging, I use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox, and Opera/Safari/IE8's built in JS debuggers.  (None of these are online, but all are pretty powerful.)  I think that [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) would make for a decent online JS debugger (in that it's a bookmarklet instead of a plugin or specific browser feature).

Comment: +1: Been using JSLint a lot lately and I love it

Answer (score 4):

It's a Firefox extension, not an online service, but you should look into [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you need to execute arbitrary JavaScript for debugging. Or [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) if you need support for other browsers.

If you're using a WebKit based browser, (Safari or Chrome), then you can use the [Web Inspector](http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/). I think that IE 8 and Opera also have equivalent features.

If you need to run JavaScript from the command line, you can use [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) directly; it has a JavaScript REPL that you can run.

Answer (score 2):

You can run/debug javascript online with [Overbyte](http://www.3site.eu/jstests/jhp/)

Comment: I keep getting "unexpected identifier" without a line number, for code that works fine in JSBin.