# What are some online Javascript tools that display execution and flow / control flow in step-by-step increments

Tags: javascript

There is an online tool where you can post javascript code and the program automatically highlights the lines based on control flow jumps and order of execution.

It's not an error console.

I can't remember the name of the URL and would like it. I'm sure there is probably more than one.

Comment: I know you can step through JS execution in Firefox with Firebug, and in the Chrome JS console, but I haven't seen a page where you can just paste your code and do a step through. 60 seconds of googling gave no results for me, so I hope somebody posts an answer, it sounds neat.

Comment: I know there is an online web tool that does this. It's really nice. It gives you forward/back buttons and jumps through the code via highlights based on it's control flow.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://jsbin.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803424/online-javascript-code-evaluation-tools

Comment: @Teemu It's not jsbin. It was a much more bland and generic project and it allowed for the code flow highlighting I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/ is one that is suppose to be good and work on a lot of browser. John Resig view on it http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/

There is also a javascript project on github that do tracing https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace but it is not as friendly cross browser wise.

Comment: The thing I'm thinking of is a lot simpler and useable for beginners. It was just very basic and did one thing only with no additional visual clutter. It thumbed through the control flow with forward and back buttons of code that you pasted in.